# How to set on click listener to nested scroll view when scrolling up in the nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-nestedscrollview

Hello am having a nested scroll view, i want to set on click listener to the nested scroll view such that it does something when am scrolling up the nested scroll view for example displaying a toast showing scrolling up when am scrolling up nested scroll view and for displaying a toast showing scrolling down when am scrolling down the nested scroll view

Here is my Nested Scroll View

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign your scroll view an id

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Declare your scroll view

```
 NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
```

Find your scroll view by id

```
 nestedScrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll_view);
```

Set an on scroll change listener to the nestedScrollView

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                if (scrollY>scrollX){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Scrolling Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Scrolling Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

And voila place your actions in the if statements

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SwipeRefreshLayout instead of NestedScrollView. You can manage scroll functionality with callbacks.

Comment: its not about swipe Refresh that i am interested, an action has to be performed when swiping up and also a different action has to be performed when swiping down, swipe refresh only provides one way only swiping down to refresh which is not what i want to achieve

Comment: For example showing a bottom sheet or a hidden layout when swiping up and hiding the bottom sheet or the hidden layout when swiping up